# How do I determine resource requests and limits for my Kubernetes deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

Let us say I am deploying a Redis server to a Kubernetes cluster.

How do I determine the resource requests and limits that I should set for my Pod?

I tried leaving resources unconfigured, but find that my pods are frequently evicted. I have Horizontal and Vertical Scaling enabled on my node pools.

Comment: I'm setting limits according to real usage, e.g. look at `top pod` to get the idea about sensible defaults.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very individual question and it is impossible to give a simple answer. Everything depends on your specific needs and your application usage pattern.

[This article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits) and the [film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjpHggHKm78) included in it present some best practices and might be very helpful when deciding how to configure requests and limits in your particular **kubernetes cluster**.

Before taking decision about configuring limits you should observe your cluster behavior for some time. [Tools for Monitoring Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/) are excellent source of such information.

> To scale an application and provide a reliable service, you need to
>   understand how the application behaves when it is deployed. You can
>   examine application performance in a Kubernetes cluster by examining
>   the containers, pods, services, and the characteristics of the overall
>   cluster. Kubernetes provides detailed information about an
>   application’s resource usage at each of these levels. This information
>   allows you to evaluate your application’s performance and where
>   bottlenecks can be removed to improve overall performance.